# react-native-webview : Downloads google drive link as html file in Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-webview

I have a google drive link shown in the webview using react-native-webview(11.25.0). And when I click on the download icon, the download happens automatically for the android platform.
But the downloaded file is not in pdf format but is an HTML file.
How can I make it download in the correct format?

This is my code :

```
<WebView
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    ref={webViewRef}
    source={{
      uri: 'https://drive.google.com/file/1_jGyMjDXhyLixkES87bhluEOnI0ZNAp7/view?usp=share_link',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment',
      },
    }}
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    allowFileAccess
    allowFileAccessFromFileURLs
    allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs
    mixedContentMode="always"
    domStorageEnabled
  />
```

I have also added the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Webview Screen with dummy pdf link from google drive[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7pLx.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfVVm.png

[image: File downloaded]

Comment: What do you consider to be a html format? You are not referring to the extension of the file? Please tell the contents of the file. What is in it?

Comment: The file that I view in the Webview is a dummy.pdf. And when I download it, I expect that pdf file to be downloaded. But instead, the 1_jGMjDXHYLi.pdf gets downloaded. And it's not viewable. @blackapps

Comment: A WebView cannot disolay a pdfdocument. And you did not tell what is in the file instead.

Comment: It's not a pdf document directly passed to Webview. Instead, it's a drive link. And the file details are mentioned here already : https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfVVm.png